# How to join three tables and display the result?

Tags: php, mysql, join, echo

I am trying to understand how to join and display data from three tables and have created these three that list person `(person)`, types of fruit `(fruit)` and the fruit the people like `(favs)`.

```
 Person               Fruit                 Favs

id  |  name        id  | type        id |  person_id  |  fruit_id

1   |  Peter        1  | apple       1  |  Peter      |  orange
2   |  Sue          2  | orange      2  |  Sue        |  apple
3   |  John         3  | banana      3  |  John       |  banana
4   |  Mary                          4  |  Peter      |  apple
                                     5  |  Sue        |  orange
```

My aim is to learn how to join all three tables and display which fruits (if any) the people like. 
Just like this:

```
Peter  | orange, apple
Sue    | apple, orange
John   | banana
Mary   |
```

I just about understand how to join all three tables to display the data above but the thing that really confuses me is how to echo out the results. Should I be using nested while loops or a foreeach loop? I've got so confused and would really appreciate someone showing me the way.
The closest I've got is this (which is far off I know).

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT person.name, favs.fruit_id 
      FROM person LEFT JOIN favs
      ON person.name = favs.person_id
      ORDER by person.id";

$result_set=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['fruit_id'];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: Your fav table should use the ids of the foreign keys, not their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in your table example data, I assume in table **Favs** you placed the names for readability, wouldn't it be the IDs themselves.  Assuming that is the case using the GROUP_CAT your SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(ft.name)
FROM favs f
INNER JOIN fruit ft ON ft.id = f.fruit_id
LEFT JOIN person p ON p.id = f.person_id
GROUP BY f.person_id
```

Comment: Well spotted, you are quite right. Your query works (I adjusted:` LEFT JOIN person p ON p.name = f.person_id`. However why is Mary is omitted from the results, she has not `favs` but she should still appear in them?

Comment: Change the LEFT JOIN to a RIGHT JOIN, note for Mary since there is no data the result will be NULL for Mary

Answer (score -1):

Just do it like this:

```
SELECT Person.id,Fruit.name FROM Person INNER JOIN Person.id=Fruit.person_id WHERE ...
```